# Progress equivalent of c# myVariable.GetType().Name?

Tags: oop, openedge, progress-4gl

Is there a Progress equivalent for C# `myVariable.GetType().Name`?

With an interface or a base type variable, can we find back the name of the real type instanciated?

```
ShowRealType(NEW myUserDefinedError()).

METHOD PUBLIC VOID ShowRealType(viError AS Progress.Lang.ERROR):
    MESSAGE /***** NEED CODE TO FIND THE REAL TYPE OF viError here ******/        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END METHOD.
```

I've tried `viError:GetClass():ToString()`, but its gives `Progress.Lang.Class_1025` instead of `myUserDefinedError`.

[image: Inheritance]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
METHOD PUBLIC VOID ShowRealType(viError AS Progress.Lang.ERROR):
    // validate that it's really an object
    if valid-object(viError) then
    MESSAGE viError:GetClass():TypeName
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END METHOD.
```